# Formal statement of well-ordering (not the theorem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The first definition of well-ordering given [on Proofwiki.org](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Well-Ordering#Definition) is:

> Let (S,⪯) be an ordered set.
>
> Then the ordering ⪯ is a well-ordering on S iff every non-empty subset
>   of S has a smallest element under ⪯:
>
> ∀T⊆S:∃a∈T:∀x∈T:a⪯x

But the formal statement here doesn't seem right. Where is the condition that `T` must be non-empty? I thought there should be something between `∀T⊆S` and the rest, e.g.

> ∀T⊆S:T≠∅→∃a∈T:∀x∈T:a⪯x

or

> ∀T⊆S:∀a∈T:∃b∈T:∀x∈T:b⪯x

Is the original statement wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition in words is correct.  Proofwiki's definition in symbols is incorrect, as the emptyset always fails to have an $a$, so no sets can satisfy the definition given in symbols.

The first proposed alternative definition in symbols is correct.  The second is a strange but correct phrasing.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the last comment? I thought that in the case `T=∅`, `∃b∈T:∀x∈T:b⪯x` would still be vacuously true for all `a∈T`, because there is no such `a`.

Comment: Okay, you're right, I've corrected the solution.